# Filtro com ChoiceField (Django)

Tags: django, django-filter

Considere meu form:

## forms.py

```
status_list = (
    ('', ''),
    ('c', 'cancelado'),
    ('elab', 'em elaboração'),
    ('p', 'pendente'),
    ('co', 'concluido'),
    ('a', 'aprovado')
)

class StatusSearchForm(forms.Form):
    status = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=status_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

## template

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="." method="get">
    <!-- status search form -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Status</label>
        {% for radio in status_search_form.status %}
            {{ radio }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <!-- search form -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="search_box" name="search_box" type="text" placeholder="Localizar..." class="form-control">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

## views.py

```
class ProposalList(ListView):
    template_name = 'core/proposal/proposal_list.html'
    model = Proposal
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProposalList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'status_search_form': StatusSearchForm(), })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        p = Proposal.objects.all().select_related()
        q = self.request.GET.get('search_box')
        if q is not None:
            try:
                p = p.filter(
                    Q(id__icontains=q) |
                    Q(work__name_work__icontains=q) |
                    Q(work__customer__first_name__icontains=q) |
                    Q(category__category__startswith=q) |
                    Q(employee__user__first_name__startswith=q) |
                    Q(seller__employee__user__first_name__startswith=q) |
                    Q(created__year=q))
            except ValueError:
                pass
        s = self.request.GET.get('status')
        if s is not None:
            p = p.filter(status__exact=s)
        elif s == '':
            p = p
        return p
```

**Pergunta**: Eu queria que quando eu escolhesse a primeira opção do 'status', que
no caso é vazio, ele retornasse todos os registros normalmente, o problema é que ele está retornando

```
http://localhost:8000/proposal/?status=&search_box=
```

E isto não retorna nada. Mas neste caso eu quero retornar tudo.

Qual seria a melhor solução?

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que retorne tudo basta verificar se o valor enviado não está vazio (`q != ''`) e então não realizar a filtragem.

```
p = Proposal.objects.all().select_related()
q = self.request.GET.get('search_box')
if not q in [None, '']:
    p = p.filter(
        Q(id__icontains=q) |
        Q(work__name_work__icontains=q) |
        Q(work__customer__first_name__icontains=q) |
        Q(category__category__startswith=q) |
        Q(employee__user__first_name__startswith=q) |
        Q(seller__employee__user__first_name__startswith=q) |
        Q(created__year=q)
    )
```

Comment: OK, mas ainda tem um erro: ValueError at /proposal/
The __year lookup type requires an integer argument

Comment: @RegisdaSilva por que você acha que está acontecendo isso?

Comment: Sim por causa dos valores inteiros, mas como tratar isso?

Comment: O erro vai acontecer porque `created___year` exige um valor do tipo `integer` para fazer a consulta e você está passando um tipo `string` que está vindo via `requesta.GET`, você tem que verficar o que o usuário está querendo buscar e com isso realizar a respectiva filtragem, se você quer filtrar `ano` você deve passar um número e não uma palavra.

Comment: Serve Q(created__year=q.strftime('%Y'))) ou Q(created__year=int(q))) ?

Comment: Regis uma solução para esta questão deve ser respondida criando uma nova pergunta, a questão original já foi respondida, não dá para ficar estendo muito pelos comentários, aqui não possibilita espaço para isso.